# left join doesn't return the rows without corrispandednt in the second table(right) when i use COUNT in the query

Tags: mysql

this query returns 2 rows

```
SELECT `users`. * , `user_bets` . *
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
```

this one returns 1 row (one of the users doesn't have any row in the `user_bets` table .

```
SELECT users. * , count(user_bets.id) as bets
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
```

but i tought it would return him any way since its a left join ? with 0 as his bets ? 
if not is there any way to get both rows with 0 as bets of the second one with join ? or should a break it in 2 query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNT()` is an *aggregate* function the count non-NULL values.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

---

Since you do not have `GROUP BY` clause, use a aggregate function like `COUNT()` is probably not what you want.

You should either add the missing `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT users. * , COUNT(user_bets.id) as bets
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Or perhaps use `IF(...)`:

```
SELECT users. * , IF(user_bets.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) as bets
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08a52/3 to experiment with that.

Comment: thanx i'm going to try it